# Can I put in a vented bathroom fan in my condo

Tags: bathroom, code-compliance, vent, exhaust-fan

I just purchased a condo in Myrtle Beach, SC - it is the first time I have owned a condo versus a house. While exploring, I found that the bathroom fans don't vent outside, they just circulate the air in the bathroom. We are planning to remodel the bathroom, and would really prefer a vented fan (assuming we can talk the HOA into putting a vent in the outside wall). But I am wondering if the ventless fan is due to fire regulations. Our condo has sprinklers and dampers on the HVAC vents that apparently close when a fire is detected. Is this possibly why the bathroom fans aren't vented outside? Does anyone know a code-related reason why a bathroom could not have a vented fan?

Comment: Most of the areas I have worked require a vented fan unless the bathroom has a window. Haven't built condos but I thought all bathrooms without 1.5 sq ft or what ever code is were required to have vented fans, in Oregon a off delay timer has been required for quite a few years not under NEC but IRC or energy code.

Comment: There is no window in the bathroom. The condo was built in 1987, so maybe the code was different then.

Comment: As far as I know there has been a requirement for a vent fan in a bathroom if there is not a window prior to the 70's, this is when I was building homes, we put fans even if there was a window but some contractors did not.